# Font Awesome: Fa Bars - Border Radius

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, font-awesome

I'm trying to remove the border radius of fa-bars and I can't.

That's my code:

```
<i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>


.fa-bars
{
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The rule is working as expected. There isn't any border-radius. Even without your styling. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/ Look, there is a border radius in the corners. I would like to remove it.

Comment: Oh wow, now I get it. Just to clarify that: This isn't any kind of `border-radius`. This simply is how that icon looks like. You can not 'remove' those smooth corners.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I'll find something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, that's not possible, since that actually is how the icon looks and nothing like a `border-radius`. You could simply use it like how it looks, or as an alternative you may take a look into Material Icons. There's an icon looking exactly how you want it to look like.

See [here](https://material.io/icons/#ic_menu).

Comment: I found a good one. I use bootstrap's icon bar and it works well.

Comment: Glad you found a soluction. Would be nice if you could select my answer as the corret one, in case it helped.

Comment: Oke. It really helped me, because I thought I can change that border radius. :)